# I have some errors in app

Tags: java

this is my code.This program searches for a specific fragment from the file that I'm setting

```
class z{
public static void main(String [] args) throws IOException{
String fileName = "file.txt";
String text = "{";
String delimiter = "}";
Optional<String> result =
               Files
                    .lines(Paths.get(fileName))
                    .filter(e -> e.contains(text))
                    .map(e -> {
                        int start = e.indexOf(text);
                        int end = e.indexOf(delimiter, start + text.length());
                        return e.substring(start, end);
                    })
                    .findFirst();

           result.ifPresent(System.out::println);
}
}
```

This code gives such an error, please help to understand why this happens, and how to fix it:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)
    at z.lambda$main$1(z.java:27)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:193)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:175)
    at java.util.Spliterators$IteratorSpliterator.tryAdvance(Spliterators.java:1812)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(ReferencePipeline.java:126)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(AbstractPipeline.java:498)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:485)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:471)
    at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(FindOps.java:152)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(ReferencePipeline.java:464)
    at z.main(z.java:29)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your stack trace has these lines:

> java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
>       at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1967)

So it's `substring` that's failing. It's probably because the `indexOf` for `end` is returning -1, which is the value returned when it isn't found.

While you filter to ensure it contains `text`, you aren't filtering that the file contains `delimiter`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are requesting index `-1`, which, if we look at the docs for [`indexOf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf(int)):

> In either case, if no such character occurs in this string, then -1 is returned.

This will occur when your search pattern does not match anything.